# What is the correct token format to send a message from firebase console?

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to test push notifications in iOS and I want to send a message manually from the Firebase console. I have converted the deviceToken to String like so:

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
```

I copy/paste the printed deviceTokenString in the message's FCM registration token input box but when I try to send the message from the console it fails and says my FCM registration token was not in the correct format. Do i need the "<>" or "-" ??? Is the APNs token used differently? I am confused as in JS and Android I haven't run into this type of issue. Thank you in advance.

I have also tried this:

```
let NSdataStr = NSData.init(data: deviceToken)
        let deviceStr = NSdataStr.description
        print(deviceStr)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this did the trick:

```
print("APNS Token: \(deviceToken.hexByteString)")
```